# how to calculate radian angle from start vector to end vector?

Tags: elixir

I want to the calculate radian anticlock wise angle (0-2*pi) from start vector to end vector. For example , start vector: {10,0}, end vector: {-10,-10}, want to get the angle {pi * 5/4}, but the result is {pi * 3/4}.

How to adjust to anticlose wise angle?

```
  def get_vector_angle({x, y}, {x1, y1}) do
    :math.acos(
      (x * x1 + y * y1) /
        (:math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) * :math.sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1 * y1))
    )
  end
```

The following is before [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) code, it can work but too long and complex.(angle: by milli degree)

```
vector_angle({X_a,Y_a},{X_b,Y_b})->
    B =case {X_b,Y_b} of
           {0,0} ->
               0;
           _ ->
               get_x_direction(0,0,X_b,Y_b)
       end,
    C = case {X_a,Y_a} of
            {0,0} ->
                0;
            _ ->
                get_x_direction(0,0,X_a,Y_a)
        end,
    case (A = (B - C )/1000) > 360 of
        true ->
            A - 360;
        false ->
            case A < 0 of
                true ->
                    A + 360;
                false ->
                    A
            end
    end.

get_x_direction({0,0})->
    0;

get_x_direction({X_b,Y_b})->
    get_x_direction(0,0,X_b,Y_b).

get_x_direction({X,Y},{X_b,Y_b})->
    get_x_direction(X,Y,X_b,Y_b).

get_x_direction(A_x,Original_y,A_y,Target_y) when (A_x == A_y orelse A_y - A_x == 0.0) 
                                                  andalso Original_y > Target_y ->
    270000;

get_x_direction(A_x,Original_y,A_y ,Target_y) when (A_x == A_y orelse A_y - A_x == 0.0) 
                                                  andalso Original_y < Target_y ->
    90000;

get_x_direction(A,Original_y,A,Target_y) when Original_y == Target_y ->
    throw(?MSG_HANOCH_DIRECTION_DATA_ERROR);

get_x_direction(Original_x,Original_y,Target_x,Target_y) when Target_y == Original_y ->
    case Target_x > Original_x of
        true ->
            0;
        false ->
            180000
    end;


get_x_direction(Original_x,Original_y,Target_x,Target_y)->
    B = round(math:atan((Target_y - Original_y)/(Target_x - Original_x))
                    * ?PI_CONVERT_2),
    C = case (Target_x - Original_x) < 0  of
        true ->
            B + 180000;
        false ->
            B
    end,
    case C < 0 of
        true->
            C + 360000;
        false ->
            C
    end.
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula you use calculate the smallest angle between the two vectors. Which will be between 0 and pi. So 3/4*pi is correct.

If you wanna get the "larger" angle, you can just subtract the found one from 2pi.

I'm not sure what you mean by differentiate between the start and end vector. Will the angle you want to find always be the "counterclockwise" one?

---

Alright :)
To determine the angle you can use that the dot product relates to cos and the determinant relates to sine, of the angle between the vectors.
Where:

dot({x,y}, {x1, y1}) = x * x1 + y * y1

det({x,y}, {x1, y1}) = x * y1 - x1 * y

Then you calculate the angle with artan2:

angle = atan2( dot(), det() )

If the angle is negative then add 2*pi and you'll find the counterclockwise one.

Just make sure that the first input vector in the determinant is your starting vector.

Comment: I have updated the question, and want to get anti clock wise angle. not just smaller or lager angle.

Answer (score 1):

Because cosine is a repeating function most implementations of arccosine return values between 0 and pi.  Take the degrees of 170 and 190.  They both produce a cosine of -.98481.  You will need to determine which quadrant you're in to find the angle you're after.  If you use sine along with cosine you can check the signs to figure out where you are.  Taking that same example as before, the value of sine for 170 and 190 are .17453 and -.17453 respectively.

A simpler approach is to use `atan2` which already takes into account quadrant.  There are a few ways to do it with `atan2` such as `atan2(y1,x1) - atan2(y,x)` or `atan2(x*y1 - y*x1, x*x1 + y*y1)`, for your example both of these will return -2.35619 radians or -135 degrees.  Since it's negative add 2 pi and you get 5/4 pi.

Comment: This, or check if the angle between two vectors is an acute angle and subtract the result of dot-product calculation from 2π otherwise.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Your method does not work for (-10,10) and (10,0). The result of dot product calculation = 3pi/4 and the angle between the vectors is obtuse but there's no need to subtract 2pi.

Comment: @Bunny Damn, I meant not acute/obtuse but <180°/>180° of course.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I think this time it won't work for (10,0) and (10,-10). The result of dot product calculation = pi/4 and the angle between the vectors < 180 but we need to subtract from 2pi to obtain the anticlockwise angle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the concept of argument from complex numbers. The argument of a complex number is the anticlockwise angle the complex number makes with the positive horizontal axis.

To calculate the argument of a vector :

- If vector is in first quadrant (y>=0 && x>=0), `arg(v) = arctan(y/x)`
- If vector is in second quadrant (y>=0 && x<=0), `arg(v) = pi - arctan(|y/x|)`
- If vector is in third quadrant (y<=0 && x<=0), `arg(v) = pi + arctan(|y/x|)`
- If vector is in fourth quadrant (y<=0 && x>=0), `arg(v) = - arctan(|y/x|)`

Now to find the anticlockwise angle between two vectors : `|arg(v1) - arg(v2)|`